# How to change the selected style on an textbox input

Tags: html, css, textbox

I am having problems trying to change the style a the textbox when it is selected. At the moment when the text box is selected in order to type in it, the box has a blue border around it which I want to get rid of.

This is my html :

```
<input type="text"class="inputs" placeholder="E-Mail" id="text-email"/>
<input type="password" class="inputs2" placeholder="Password" id="text-password"/>
```

This is my css {

```
.inputs  { 
    background: #282b32;
    display: block; 
    padding: 12px 10px; 
    color: #ffb900;
    font-size: 3.6em; 
    font-family: headingFont;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-left: 0px;
    border-right: 0px;
    width:570px;
    height:61px;
    text-align: center;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #ffb900;
}

#text-email {
    position: absolute;
    left:25px;
    top: 250px;
}

#text-password {
    position: absolute;
    left:25px;
    top: 335px;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `outline:0;` to remove blue border

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this css

```
outline:0;
```

Here is [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/u2JVJ/)

Answer (score 2):

```
.input
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
}
.input:focus
{
    border:  solid 1px #000;
}

<input type="text" class="input"/>
```

you can use focus property for text box

Answer (score 1):

Look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/33ntR/1/

html

```
<input type="text"class="inputs" placeholder="E-Mail" id="text-email"/>
<input type="password" class="inputs2" placeholder="Password" id="text-password"/>
```

css

```
.inputs  { 
background: #282b32;
display: block; 
padding: 12px 10px; 
color: #ffb900;
font-size: 3.6em; 
font-family: headingFont;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
border-top: 0px;
border-left: 0px;
border-right: 0px;
width:570px;
height:61px;
text-align: center;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
color: #ffb900;
}

#text-email {
position: absolute;
left:25px;
top: 250px;
}

#text-password {
position: absolute;
left:25px;
top: 335px;
}

#text-email:focus{
    background-color:red;
    border:10px solid #cdcdcd;
}

#text-password:focus{
    background-color:green;
    border:4px solid #caaaaa;
}
```

The main content is the :focus attribute in css.
For further information http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp